# How do I configure CodeIgniter to fetch information from a specific database?

Tags: database, codeigniter-2

I'm relatively new to the CodeIgniter framework (I'm using v2).

I'll need to write an application, in such a way that users do their login to a central DB. After successfully logging in, the user is then redirected to their back-end, which should connect to their specific database, which is stored in the login table for each user.

How can I set the configs for CodeIgniter to be able to fetch information from the correct DB?

I want to achieve something like this:

```
$config['default']['database'] = "Logins"
$config['specific']['database'] = get_user_database();
```

Is this possible in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

At first impression, you have two options:

1. Set the config value as

   ```
   $this->config->set_item('specific', array('database' => get_user_database()));
   ```
2. Use [Hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html), could be at `pre_controller` hook point

Comment: Does this serves multiple databases in one application? I'm not suprised if the application needs to get access to 10 different databases for different users. My concern is that, if one user needs to write in a database, other user that accesses it would stop the query from the previous one... Should I be concerned with this??

Comment: Remeber that everytime the application is loaded, it trigger a database connection again. So, if a user change the database connection un execution context, it only will affect the user in question and does not the other ones.